# How do you make quick edits to a pip installable library before commiting

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have an existing pip library, however I would like to make modifications to it over time. I have the pip library installed from a github project in a virtualenv. The only options I can think of for making edits before deciding a change is worth actually committing and pushing to the cloud is to edit the library directly within site-packages, which is particularly annoying as the virtualenv is stored within a docker container. Are there any short cuts or best practices to improve this workflow?

Answer (score 1):

pip offers the `-e` option for [editable installs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs). This is very similar to running [`setup.py develop`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#development-mode) to put a package in "development mode". This way you can keep your code where you want and change it as needed, without having to reinstall after fixing every syntax error and refactoring.